# Webview showing html tags not actual required data?

Tags: android, android-emulator

[image: emulator shows this output]

I have parsed the data and stored in string and loaded it with web-view then it showing HTML tags in emulator. But when I run same app on another machine it will show me the actual webpage. Is it problem with emulator or another?? I have already given the internet permissions and also set proxy settings.In emulator browser all webpages are working.  Please check my code.

```
String vidushImg;
URL url=null;
```

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.news); 
 Intent newsIntent=getIntent();
 vidushImg=newsIntent.getStringExtra("ss");
 showWeb();
```

}

```
private void showWeb() 
{
    WebView webview = new WebView(this); 
    setContentView(webview); 
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    Log.v("....hello....","");
    webview.loadData(vidushImg,"text/html","utf-8");

}


   The value of vidushImg-----> 
    <div style="text-align: center;"><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-weight: normal; font-size: medium; "><img src="http://mobileecommerce.site247365.com/admin/assetmanager/images/gns_header.jpg" alt="" align="middle" border="1px" height="90" width="550"></span></div><span class="Apple-style-span" style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-family: Verdana; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; "><br><div style="text-align: center;">Yes we are coming at E & I? Are you?</div></span><br><h1 style="font-weight: bold; "><span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 14pt; ">News for the day...</span></h1><span style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); "><span style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt; ">Template Mobile Sites for IC: <a href="http://icmobilesite.vidushiinfotech.net/">http://icmobilesite.vidushiinfotech.net/</a></span><br><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 13px; color: rgb(105, 105, 105); ">Promotional valid till 30 Sept 2011: MOBILE WEBSITE (Base Product Mobile CMS) for JUST $159<br></span></span><br><span style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(105, 105, 105); ">Mobile Template link: </span><a href="http://newsletter.vidushiinfotech.net/Mobilesite/"><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; color: rgb(105, 105, 105); ">http://newsletter.vidushiinfotech.net/Mobilesite/</span><br></a><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Tahoma; "><span style="font-size: 10pt; "><br><span style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); ">With the promotion on Business Edge and eFusion still running successful in e market place - $ 499</span><br><span style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); ">Check out some of the latest site launch on: </span><br><br><span style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-weight: bold; ">http://www.randallcontracting.co.uk/Pages/Default.aspx </span><br><br><span style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-size: 10pt; "><span style="font-weight: bold; ">Category</span>: Building & Construction</span><br></span><br></span><div style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); text-align: left; "><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Tahoma; ">Description: WELCOME TO RANDALL CONTRACTING Randall Contracting is a family-run contracting SME which has been servicing London and the South East since 1956. Working closely with our Clients and external Design Consultants, we place great emphasis on a safe, positive, practical and common sense approach to our projects. Our delivery methods have resulted in an extensive volume of repeat business from both Private and Public Sectors. Safety and Environmental concerns are a high priority on all our contracts and we continually strive to source innovative working methods and solutions. Our equipment is regularly updated and maintained to ensure minimal environmental impact.</span><br><br></div><span style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-weight: bold; font-family: Tahoma; "><span style="font-size: 10pt; "><br></span></span><br>
```

Comment: Can you provide the value of `vidushImg`?

Comment: Can you open any other webpage, like google.com?

Comment: @saptulamania: Thanks for replay. I edited my code and provided value of vidushImg at the end please check it.

Comment: @Reno:Thanks for reply.Yes other webpages are working well in emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, Its working fine here with the below:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class DemoExampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String strWeb = "<div style=\"text-align: center;\"><span class=\"Apple-style-span\" style=\"font-weight: normal; font-size: medium; \"><img src=\"http://mobileecommerce.site247365.com/admin/assetmanager/images/gns_header.jpg\" alt=\"\" align=\"middle\" border=\"1px\" height=\"90\" width=\"550\"></span></div><span class=\"Apple-style-span\" style=\"color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-family: Verdana; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; \"><br><div style=\"text-align: center;\">Yes we are coming at E & I? Are you?</div></span><br><h1 style=\"font-weight: bold; \"><span style=\"font-family: Verdana; font-size: 14pt; \">News for the day...</span></h1><span style=\"color: rgb(105, 105, 105); \"><span style=\"font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt; \">Template Mobile Sites for IC: <a href=\"http://icmobilesite.vidushiinfotech.net/\">http://icmobilesite.vidushiinfotech.net/</a></span><br><span class=\"Apple-style-span\" style=\"font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 13px; color: rgb(105, 105, 105); \">Promotional valid till 30 Sept 2011: MOBILE WEBSITE (Base Product Mobile CMS) for JUST $159<br></span></span><br><span style=\"font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(105, 105, 105); \">Mobile Template link: </span><a href=\"http://newsletter.vidushiinfotech.net/Mobilesite/\"><span class=\"Apple-style-span\" style=\"font-size: 15px; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; color: rgb(105, 105, 105); \">http://newsletter.vidushiinfotech.net/Mobilesite/</span><br></a><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; font-family: Tahoma; \"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; \"><br><span style=\"color: rgb(105, 105, 105); \">With the promotion on Business Edge and eFusion still running successful in e market place - $ 499</span><br><span style=\"color: rgb(105, 105, 105); \">Check out some of the latest site launch on: </span><br><br><span style=\"color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-weight: bold; \">http://www.randallcontracting.co.uk/Pages/Default.aspx </span><br><br><span style=\"color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-size: 10pt; \"><span style=\"font-weight: bold; \">Category</span>: Building & Construction</span><br></span><br></span><div style=\"color: rgb(105, 105, 105); text-align: left; \"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; font-family: Tahoma; \">Description: WELCOME TO RANDALL CONTRACTING Randall Contracting is a family-run contracting SME which has been servicing London and the South East since 1956. Working closely with our Clients and external Design Consultants, we place great emphasis on a safe, positive, practical and common sense approach to our projects. Our delivery methods have resulted in an extensive volume of repeat business from both Private and Public Sectors. Safety and Environmental concerns are a high priority on all our contracts and we continually strive to source innovative working methods and solutions. Our equipment is regularly updated and maintained to ensure minimal environmental impact.</span><br><br></div><span style=\"color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-weight: bold; font-family: Tahoma; \"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; \"><br></span></span><br>";
        WebView webview = new WebView(this); 
        setContentView(webview); 
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        webview.loadData(strWeb,"text/html","utf-8");
    }
}
```

[image]

### Update:

1. Add the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` permission in AndroidManifest.xml file.
2. Why are you calling again setContentView() method again in showWeb() method, instead you can directly take a WebView inside that news xml layout file and refer it.
3. In other case, **`Check your Internet Connection`**.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it is not working on my emulator , I recreated the emulator twice then also it is not working . Where is problem ? any idea?

Comment: I have already given the Internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml file and i also tried secod way that taking webview in xml file and finding it by id then loading data into it. But it also not worked for me. I noticed one thing that in my emulator when it is not showing 3G tag at status bar then internet not working thing my application but at same time in emulator browser internet working properly why is it so? Is this problem is related to this question??

Comment: There may be a problem of Internet connection. Just test the same example once in real device.